# UIFont not being set in UILabel- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uifont

I have a UILabel and want the font of the text to be SF Mono. So, I use these lines of code:

```
let tagBoxLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
tagBoxLabel.font = UIFont(name: "SF Mono Regular", size: 10.0)
```

But the text is not set. I have a tried "SFMono-Regular", "SFMono-Regular.otf", etc. Nothing.

I have correctly imported the .OTF into my project as well, as I can access it on the storyboard.

Does anyone have any clue of what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that the font was not entered properly in Xcode.

First, drag and drop your font file into the Xcode project IN FINDER

Second, drag and drop it into Xcode into the project navigator and click "Copy items if needed" and assign the target membership to your target. This is super important

Third, go to your info.plist and enter your font into there using "Fonts provided by application" This is what did it for me.

Fourth, make sure you're using the correct name. It might not be what the file name is.

Hope anyone who finds this is helped by it!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are not using the correct font name. Try this:

```
let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames
for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
print("------------------------------")
print("Font Family Name = [\(familyName)]")
let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
print("Font Names = [\(names)]")
}
```

Can you try getting the font name from there and implement it and run it again? I got this code from http://giordanoscalzo.tumblr.com/post/95900320382/print-all-ios-fonts-in-swift

Second:

```
    UIFont.familyNames.forEach({ familyName in
        let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
        print(familyName, fontNames)
    })
```

Comment: Nothing turns up. Does that mean I didn't import the font correctly?

Comment: You have it in your viewDidLoad? It works for me... I added a second option but it should work. It should print all the default fonts as well.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using this guide to add fonts in my apps and its the best thing. Do make sure you check for **Copy Bundle Resources** section in your **Build Phases**.

[Follow this link and get the right way of adding your fonts to the app.](https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

> Go to your project Build Phases pane by highlighting the XCode project file in your solution explorer and on the right hand side, select “Build Phases”. You’ll see that one of the sections you can expand is “Copy Bundle Resources”. Open that list and make sure that your fonts are included in that list.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)